# When a class extends another class and also implements an interface, shouldn't it override all the abstract methods of the parent class and interface?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, laravel-10

As far as I know,
when a class extending another class, It's should override all abstract methods of parent class and It can also override non-abstract methods
And also when a class implementing an interface, It's should override all of the parent interface methods
but I've seen a Laravel project that didn't do this

This is the parent interface:

```
<?php

interface MustVerifyEmail
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user has verified their email address.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasVerifiedEmail();

    /**
     * Mark the given user's email as verified.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function markEmailAsVerified();

    /**
     * Send the email verification notification.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendEmailVerificationNotification();

    /**
     * Get the email address that should be used for verification.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmailForVerification();
}
```

this is the parent class:

```
<?php

class User extends Model implements
    AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, MustVerifyEmail;
}
```

and this is the child class:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];

    public function activeCode()
    {
        return //...
    }

    public function hasTwoFactor($key)
    {
        return //...
    }

    public function isTwoFactorAuthEnabled()
    {
        return //...
    }
}
```

How did this happen?

Comment: I'm not a Laravel user, but I can't fully understand your example. You have two elements called `MustVerifyEmail` (an interface and a trait) and you have two classes called `User`. You claim the first `User` is the parent class, but the child class extends `Authenticatable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: User model inherits the implementation from its parent model, while the later delegated the implementation to `trait MustVerifyEmail`.

---

These methods were actually explicitly implemented, just not on the class itself but on its `traits`.

> Traits are a mechanism for code reuse in single inheritance languages such as PHP. A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in several independent classes living in different class hierarchies. ([From PHP's Traits](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php))

In this particular case you might be confused by two homonym oop structures: `interface MustVerifyEmail` vs `trait MustVerifyEmail`. Your User model states that the interface will be implemented by it, which is true but not strictly because the one actually implementing it is the parent class `Authenticatable`. *But when did it implement it?* That is where the `use` keyword gets into action:

While `implements` is for Interfaces, the `use` is for Traits. Parent User class is "using" the `trait MustVerifyEmail`, in other words, it is attaching the trait to itself, thus "inheriting" all of its methods.